# How to write stored procedure to check Grant in MySql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure to check grant. I have tried by following way but I don't what I am missing here.

```
//simple Query "SHOW GRANTS FOR testuser @'192.168.1.180'"  - It is working

CREATE DEFINER=`abc`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_GetGrantAllPriviledge`(
IN Username TEXT,
IN Hostname TEXT
)
BEGIN
   SHOW GRANTS FOR Username @Hostname; //doesn't work
END
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Hostname; is the source of issue
```

Update your SP with prepare statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_GetGrantAllPriviledge`(
IN Username TEXT,
IN Hostname TEXT
)
BEGIN

   SET @sql = CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',Username,' @',Hostname,'; ');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Comment: it doesn't work if I pass this 2 parameter in Hostname to check grant. 1- "::1", 2- "192.168.%". It throws syntax error. It run perfect if I pass in query.

Comment: show me the call process...for my case I have used call SP_GetGrantAllPriviledge('root','localhost')

Comment: Try to check this stored procedure by passing "::1" instead of "locahost". Also try to execute query directly in query window. It works fine in query window. But it throws syntax error in stored procedure.

Comment: when I tried to use `SHOW GRANTS FOR root @:1;` it shows me error in query window also

Comment: Create a test user with host "::1". Then execute this `SHOW GRANTS FOR test_user @'::1'`

Comment: Done. SET @sqlParameter = CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',Username,' @','\'',Hostname,'\'','; ');

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TABLE_PRIVILEGES in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
WHERE `GRANTEE` = CONCAT('''', Username, '''@''', Hostname, '''')
```

Comment: I have tried to this way but it doesn't return privilege. You can try both: 1- Your query: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES WHERE `GRANTEE` = 'root @localhost'` and this 2-  `SHOW GRANTS FOR root @'localhost'`. 2nd will return list of Grant but 1st doesn't. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Do you want to reproduce the output of `SHOW GRANTS` exactly or you are looking for specific information? All the privileges can be found in (and the output of SHOW GRANTS simulated exactly) via COLUMN_PRIVILEGES, SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES, TABLE_PRIVILEGES, and USER_PRIVILEGES.

Comment: I want to reproduce the output of SHOW GRANTS exactly. Currently, I get this in MySqlReader = "query". Like this. Can you please suggest?